# Why are these two pages displaying differently on ipad?

Tags: html, ios, css, ipad

http://kilgorerodriguez.com/index.html
&
http://kilgorerodriguez.com/CarlosRodriguez.html

On the second page the background spans the entire page but on the first page it cuts off.  I'm guessing it's something with CSS, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Safari Developer Tools are your friend.

Comment: Try right click > inspect element

Comment: At a glance, there's a lot of problems with the syntax of the HTML in the first page. e.g. `<div id="content_main_bio style=" min-width:1124px="" padding-left:0px="">` and `<h1 style="color: rgba(34,64,115,1);" font-weight:lighter="">`. The HTML looks cleaner in the second example.

Comment: Yeah @esker, that is my attempt at debugging.  I'm thinking I just need to start from scratch with the first page.  I was hoping someone could 'see' something obvious that I'm overlook.  Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the Xcode developer tools installed on your Mac, you can attach the Safari Web Inspector to the iPad Simulator, like this:

1. Open the iOS simulator:open Xcode, then go to menu *Xcode > Open Developer Tool > iOS Simulator*
2. Change the hardware mode in the simulator to iPad
3. Open the Settings app on the simulator, go to *Safari > Advanced* and set *Web Inspector* to *On*
4. Follow the instructions under the Web Inspector switch: open the desired web page in Safari in the iPad Simulator, and also open the desktop version of Safari on the Mac. Go to the *Develop > iPad Simulator* menu in Safari and choose the appropriate page

Now you'll have a Web Inspector window that is attached to the web page in the iPad Simulator, with full power to debug the web page.

I used this to find the bad HTML markup I mentioned in the comment. When I used the Web Inspector to fix that markup (find the HTML element in the Resource tab or use the hand icon to select the element in the simulator window, then right click the element and choose *Edit as HTML*), and then also changed the style attribute for that div I mentioned to have `min-width: 1002px;`, the page looked OK in the iPad Simulator for me. The change to 1002px is based on one of the parent elements, `<div id="wrapper">`, having `width: 1002px` defined in the CSS. The wider min-width of 1124px probably caused the page width problem.

Comment: Thanks for the help, @esker.  It was the wrapper div afterall.  Also, thanks for the heads up on Xcode